# scala var failed to get appended value outside foreach loop

Tags: scala, foreach, apache-spark

I have a text file named vertexDict which has multiple key value pairs splitted by "\1",and i need to convert this to a Map in my spark program.Here is my code:

```
var mapDict = Map[Long, String]()
sc.textFile(vertexDict).map(line=> line.split("\1")).foreach(a=>{
  if(a.length ==2 ){
    mapDict += a(0).toLong->a(1)
  }
})
```

problem is mapDict is still empty after the foreach loop end,but i debuged into the loop, and mapDict successfully added the elements into it;so I bypass this problem by:

```
val mapDict = sc.textFile(vertexDict).map(line=> line.split("\1")).map(a=>a(0).toLong->a(1)).collect().toMap
```

it works.But i still don't know why foreach failed to add.
thanks!

Comment: The `"\1"` does not compile. Can you paste the actual code?

Comment: "\1" is just a delimeter i use and could be anything.this is my actual code ,other part of codes are huge and does nothing with this problem.

Comment: your need mapDict to be mutable to append values to it

Comment: i declare it as a var,is that not enough?what should i do?

Comment: make it as 
scala.collection.mutable.Map[Long, String]()

Comment: tried but not work,still zero size

Comment: are you sure that if statement works actually ?

Comment: @Hackaholic the map doesn't **have** to be mutable. The way OP uses it is fine, the `+=` will create a new immutable instance from the current version of the map, with the new key-value added to it.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some problem with your logic. The correct logic is:

```
var mapDict = Map[Long, String]()
val str = "1234\1hello\n3456\1world"
str.lines.foreach{line => 
  val a = line.split("\1")
  if(a.length == 2) {
    mapDict += (a(0).toLong->a(1))
  }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
scala> mapDict foreach println
(1234,hello)
(3456,world)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather imperative approach to the problem. The FP approach is to see this as a collection of lines, from which you want to generate a map taken from lines which match a certain criterion (here, having two items). Try:

```
val str = "1234\1hello\nNonmatching line\n3456\1world\nAline\1with too\1many matches"
val mapDict = str.lines.map( a => a.split("\1")).collect {case Array(k,v) => k->v}.toMap
```

I added a 1-item line, and 3-item line to demonstrate they are filtered out. This gives:

```
mapDict: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(1234 -> hello, 3456 -> world)
```

Notice that you don't need to mapDict to be a var any more.

Answer (score 0):

I finally know why modify the Map collection in the foreach loop doesn't work:because spark run parallelly and the map collection is changed in different partition, the solution I pasted in my question just use the rdd operation collect to get all partition data to driver and run toMap locally.
So the solution is to use spark accumulator instead.